# Эклипс не выводит значения заданные в операторе system.out.print в консоль, помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: java, консоль

```
public class Weapons {
    
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    class Weapons1 {
      int ammo;
      int bullet;   

      int power() {
        return ammo+bullet;
      }

      Weapons1(int a, int b) {

        ammo = a;
        bullet = b;

        Weapons1 m16 = new Weapons1(1, 1);
        Weapons1 m249 = new Weapons1(2, 2);

        System.out.println(m16.power()+m249.bullet);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Конечно не выводится. Ведь этот код ничего не делает.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Weapons {

  static class Weapons1 {
    int ammo;
    int bullet;   

    int power() {
      return ammo+bullet;
    }

    Weapons1(int a, int b) {
      ammo = a;
      bullet = b;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Weapons1 m16 = new Weapons1(1, 1);
    Weapons1 m249 = new Weapons1(2, 2);

    System.out.println(m16.power()+m249.bullet);
  }
}
```

Comment: А можете пояснить почему так, просто хочу знать чтобы не ошибаться больше

Comment: @Akihiro Потому что Вы зачем-то поместили определение класса внутрь метода `main`. А собственно кода в методе `main` вообще не было.

Comment: Спасибо, учту))

Comment: @Akihiro Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.